# Python - How to check whether a string contains an item from a list, and when returns true, have the item from the list as index usable in the loop

Tags: python

Basically how I'd like it to be, is:

- Loop that checks if string contains one of the strings/items from the list. Basically, "for when current index of list returns true upon finding, append that item as string to a new list"

Example from another post:

```
some_list = ['abc-123', 'def-456', 'ghi-789', 'abc-456']
for any("abc" in s for s in some_list):
    #s isn't the index, right?
```

Well, the question basically is, how do I do the above. Sorry for my poor formatting and English, and such.

Example:

I have a string  `"La die la Blablabla and flowers are red"`

I have an array *TheArray*, `['Blablabla', 'thisonewillnotbefound', 'flowers', 'thisonenoteither', 'red']`

And I need a loop that goes through every item in the array, and whenever it finds one that exists in it, it will be appended to a completely new list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Python, how do I find the index of an item given a list containing it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/in-python-how-do-i-find-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it)

Comment: try to add some input and expected output, it is not clear what you really want to do.

Comment: I will try - however I have to think about how, because I hardly have an idea what I'm doing myself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This would give you a list of indexes of the list where the word was found in the text

```
>>> text = 'Some text where the words should be'
>>> words = ['text', 'string', 'letter', 'words']
>>> [i for i, x in enumerate(words) if x in text]
[0, 3]
```

[`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) will take an iterator and give another one with tuples where the first element is an index starting at 0 and the second is an element from the iterator you passed to it.

`[i for i, x in ...]` is a [`list comprehension`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is just a short form of writing a for loop

Comment: Sorry, but apparently my question was rather badly formatted; I edited it to make it seem more clear. I don't have trouble with the new list I'd have to make, I just need to figure out how to catch the index of the item of the array the loop is currently at when it returns true upon searching in the string.

Comment: You just did it!! Thanks so much for your amazing reading comprehension! I know my question was a bunch of bullshit - so understand wtf I meant was quite hard. Thanks for your time. Enumerate is something I personally won't touch yet myself, I have to stay sane. However, your code works perfectly, so that's alright.

Comment: Wouldn't it be quite easy to make it return ['text', 'words'] instead of the index too, then? Just wondering, for myself to learn.

Comment: sure, to do that just use `filter(lambda x: x in text, words)`